# jQuery fadeOut is not changing display property

Tags: jquery, slideshow, fadein, fadeout

On http://judi.simpleupdates.com/ I am attempting to make a slideshow of images on a page using the jQuery `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effects. Both items `fadeIn` without issue. However, `fadeOut` is not changing the `display` property of the `div` that is supposed to disappear. Any ideas why this might not be working as expected?

This is the line that is failing:

```
$( ".carousel_item:nth-child(" + selected + ")" ).fadeOut(600);
```

**UPDATE:** The issue seems to be with `fadeOut` on a element that does not have a `width` and `height`. When values are added to the `width` and `height` properties of `div.carousel_item` the `fadeOut` call works properly. Another method is to remove `position: absolute` from the descendant `img` causing the `div` to grow to the `img` dimensions.

Comment: Can you provide some lines of code from your app?

Comment: can you please remove the comment of the fadeout so we can test it

Comment: code in question is now live. sorry about that :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue seems to be with `fadeOut` on a element that does not have a `width` and `height`. when values are added to the `width` and `height` properties of `div.carousel_item` the `fadeOut` call works properly. another method is to remove `position: absolute` from the descendant `img` causing the `div` to grow to the `img` dimensions.

thanks for all of your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

<del>Changing the display setting in the HTML to `<div id="txt2" class="carousel_item" style="display: none; ">` should trigger the fadeIn/fadeOut correctly.</del>

<del>You may also need to change the jQuery to:
    `$( ".carousel_item:nth-child(" + selected + ")" ).fadeOut(600).hide();`</del>

<del>You're calling fadeIn/fadeOut on items that are both set to `display: block`. It needs alternate states in order to work.</del>

**UPDATE**
After downloading a local copy of your site, changing the showhide() function in your js to:

```
var inc = 1
function showhide(current) {
    if (inc == 1) current = 2;
    $( ".carousel_item:nth-child(" + selected + ")" ).fadeIn(600);
    $( ".carousel_item:nth-child(" + current + ")" ).fadeOut(600).hide();
    selected = current;
    inc++;
}
```

works in my testing. Hopefully, it works for you. I added the counter as your initial count seems to set both `selected` and `current` to 1.

Comment: all divs with the .carousel_item class are already set to display: none; in the external css file. the display property is changed to block only after fadeIn has been called on that particular div. i also tried setting the value inline without solving the problem.

Comment: this suggestion did work for me. the one problem is that if more items are added to the slideshow (controlled by the customer) then it would not work. so your solution was correct given the information that you had. **final solution** discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you just have to replace the current and the selected variables with each other in the jQuery-selector? when i understand it right you want to fadeout the current and fadein the selected, don't you?

Comment: no, `current` is the `div` that is to be shown and `selected` is the item that is to disappear, though i like your suggestion of switching the variable names if it is done throughout the file.